# How can I embed an AVI video in a PowerPoint presentation?

Tags: video, microsoft-powerpoint, avi

I am trying to embed an AVI video in my PowerPoint presentation.  I've inserted it as a "movie" but when I actually run the slideshow, the video flashes black consistently and is unwatchable.

Anybody have any ideas on what might be happening or a better route to take in embedding a video into my PowerPoint presentation?

Comment: Is it just a specific AVI file that's giving you this trouble or all AVI files?  Does the AVI you're having this trouble with work when played through Windows Media Player?

Comment: No trouble when playing through WMP just when embedding into powerpoint.  And it has done it on two seperate avi's

Comment: There's always the option of making it a Google Docs Presentation and embedding the video as a YouTube video.. :D

Answer (score 1):

I've found other people complaining of the same thing when using AVI's in PP (yet they play fine in WMP), with no real explanations or solutions.

The best advice seems to be to convert the AVI to another format before embedding it, and your best bet is probably WMV.

There are about a million different converters out there for you to try/choose from (depending on your OS).  There's also on-line conversion services (like http://video.online-convert.com).

Comment: Yes exactly. I have had this happen twice. Converting the AVI to WMV(which is a more MS compatible format) and it's fine. Xilinix converter isn't free but converts fine, haven't tried others recently.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you use PowerPoint 2010, you can't embed videos in PowerPoint.  They're always linked.

If your OS/video driver permits it, try setting video hardware acceleration all the way back, then try playing the slide with video on it.  If that works, keep bumping accel back up a notch at a time until the video ceases playing, bump accel back down one, verify that the video plays.

At that point, you at least have a workaround that'll let you play the video.

You might then want to check for updated video drivers.

Answer (score 0):

- Display the slide in which you want to add a video clip.
- On the Insert menu, point to Movies and Sounds, and then click Movie from Clip Organizer.
- Click the movie you want to add to your slide.
- To maintain the image’s original proportions, drag one of the corner sizing handles.
- To change the original proportions, drag one of the sizing handles in the center of a border.
- To change the image’s size without displacing the center of the image (that is, to resize it symmetrically about the center), press CTRL while you drag a sizing handle.
- To move the video image, drag it to a new location.